# Spark scala schema not enforced on load

Tags: java, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I was trying out a Spark scala example on the spark shell which is as follows;

```
val myManualSchema = StructType(Array(StructField("DEST_COUNTRY_NAME", StringType, true), 
StructField("ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME",StringType
, true), StructField("count", LongType, nullable=false)))

val dfNew = spark.read.format("json").schema(myManualSchema).load("/test.json")

dfNew.printSchema()
```

The output I got was as follows;

```
root
|-- DEST_COUNTRY_NAME: string (nullable = true)
|-- ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME: string (nullable = true)
|-- count: long (nullable = true)
```

I was expecting the `count` column to be `nullable=false` but it does not seem to be enforced. However, when I create a new DataFrame from this one and set the schema there, it works. This is what I did;

```
val dfSchemaTest = spark.createDataFrame(dfNew.rdd,myManualSchema)

scala> dfSchemaTest.printSchema()
root
 |-- DEST_COUNTRY_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- count: long (nullable = false)
```

I would appreciate if someone can point my error in the following for not enforcing the schema when done at the time of loading the data file.

Comment: In some circumstances, spark will infer the data types according to the data in file. Maybe you do have some null values in this file?

Comment: @bupt_ljy thank you for the response. I did check the file and verified that there are no null values for `count`

Comment: one may not be able to enforce schema while reading from JSON , CSV but 
as you mentioned is the only feasible way I could think : 
```val df = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd,myManualSchema)```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing, that can be done, as nullability is enforced by file format. It's just what spark does - if the datasource cannot ensure, that the column is not null, neither can `DataFrame` while read.